# id inside a link inside a label on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to put an id in a link that's inside a lable in rails

```
<%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me, ("I accept the #{link_to 'Terms & Conditions', '#'} of website.").html_safe %>
```

How do I add and ID to the `Terms & Conditions` link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `id` attribute in `html_options` param of [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) method:

```
link_to 'Terms & Conditions', '#', id: 'link_id'
```